# リスト内で部分一致する要素を取り出す

Tags: python

```
['AAA_1p', 'AAA_2p', 'BBB_1p' , 'CCC_1p', 'CCC_2p', 'CCC_3p']
```

上記のリストから

```
['AAA_2p', 'BBB_1p','CCC_3p'] # 最大の数
['AAA_2p', 'BBB_1p','CCC_2p'] # 2ｐがあれば2ｐ、なければ1ｐ(3ｐは無視)
```

のような2パターンの要素を取り出したいのですが、処理方法が全く思いつきません。
良い処理方法があればお教えください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: AAA_2pのAAAの部分と2pの部分を分けたリスト(かタプル)に変換してから考えるのはいかがですか？

Answer (score 1):

以下は [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) を使う方法です。

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = ['AAA_1p', 'AAA_2p', 'BBB_1p' , 'CCC_1p', 'CCC_2p', 'CCC_3p']

# 最大の数
>>> [list(g)[-1] for _, g in groupby(sorted(lst), lambda x: x.split('_')[0])]
['AAA_2p', 'BBB_1p', 'CCC_3p']

# 2pがあれば2p、なければ1p(3pは無視)
>>> [
  next((f'{k}_{i}p' for i in (2, 1) if f'{k}_{i}p' in g))
  for k, g in
    ((k, list(gp)) for k, gp in groupby(sorted(lst), lambda x: x.split('_')[0]))
  if any((f'{k}_{i}p' in g for i in (1, 2)))
]
['AAA_2p', 'BBB_1p', 'CCC_2p']
```

2番目の処理についてですが、サフィックスとして `_2p` か `_1p` が付いていない要素が存在する場合を考慮しています。具体例としては、以下の様なリストになります(`DDD_4p`)。

```
['AAA_1p', 'AAA_2p', 'BBB_1p' , 'CCC_1p', 'CCC_2p', 'CCC_3p', 'DDD_4p']
```